# Selenium C# disabled button

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to check somehow whether the button is able to be pressed. I'm using "Enabled", both results (button which an able of being pressed / button which is not) are set on true value.

I wanted to get Attribute / Property but no idea what exactly should be taken from the DOM:

```
<div class="w-90 text-right m-auto">
<div class="btn" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; min-width: 88px;">
    <button disabled="" tabindex="-1" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: default; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); text-align: center;">
        <div style="height: 36px; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;">
            <span style="position: relative; opacity: 1; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; user-select: none; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);">Refund selected</span>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="btn" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; min-width: 88px;">
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <div style="height: 36px; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;">
                <span style="position: relative; opacity: 1; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; user-select: none; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);">Print Receipt Copy</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="btn" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; min-width: 88px;">
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <div style="height: 36px; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;">
                <span style="position: relative; opacity: 1; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; user-select: none; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);">Refund receipt</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="btn" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 1px 4px; border-radius: 2px; display: inline-block; min-width: 88px;">
    <button tabindex="0" type="button" style="border: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; outline: none; font-size: inherit; font-weight: inherit; position: relative; height: 36px; line-height: 36px; width: 100%; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <div style="height: 36px; border-radius: 2px; transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; top: 0px;">
                <span style="position: relative; opacity: 1; font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: 500; margin: 0px; user-select: none; padding-left: 16px; padding-right: 16px; color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);">Copy receipt</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

As you can see there is word button disabled tabindex = "-1" in button which is disabled and button tabindex = "0" when button is able of being pressed.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

`disabled` attribute return `bool`, you can check if `GetAttribute()` returns `true`.

```
string disabledAttribute = element.GetAttribute("disabled");
if (disabledAttribute)
{
    // element has "disabled" attribute
}
```

Comment: When I'm getting attribute like you said I'm receiving null from the button which is disabled. Is it correct?

Comment: @Ixi11 you are receiving `null` from the disabled or enabled button? you might get it from the enabled one.

Comment: I'm getting it from the disabled one :(